# Remove programmatically generated layout in Widget usin RemoteView

Tags: android, android-widget, dynamically-generated, remoteview

I am creating a widget for Android but I'm facing an issue.
I have a container in my main widget layout, and I want to add it new line in the list dynamically.
For that, I use the addView methods on the RemoteViews of my container:

Widget.java

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    RemoteViews rowView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
    views.addView(R.id.list_container, rowView);
}
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</LinearLayout>
```

widget.xml

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
...
```

So now, I have a Layout with 10 lines/copy of my row layout.
But each line has the same id depending of the one i put in my layout/row.xml.

**I want now to delete a row, how can I do this because all row have the same id ?**

- I can't change the id of my row because RemoteViews doesn't seem to accept the setId(id) method
- Remove all views not working as I expected :

```java
     views.removeAllViews(R.id.row);
```

- It only removes the first row.

Anyone with and idea of how this works ? Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way or widget layout are not made to be programmatically defined ?

Comment: How about setting different ids dynamically to each row

Comment: I didn't find how to achieve this because setId() is not a method of RemoteViews. I'm working on a widget so I have to deel with RemoteViews, not Views!

Comment: So, RemoveViews is not Views .. how you want to do this `views.addView(R.id.list_container, rowView)` .. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128347/remoteviews-id-in-loops)

Comment: My variable is called "views" but its a RemoteViews and this class has a "addView" method, it take a RemoteView in parameter : [RemoteViews.addView() Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#addView(int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews))

Comment: Are you making partial updates to this widget? Or are you doing a full update each time? If it's the latter, then you just need to reconstruct the `RemoteViews` the same way, but without the item that's deleted.

Comment: Btw, `removeAllViews()` is working as it should. It's not meant to remove all `View`s with the given ID. It removes the `View`s _inside_ the one you pass it; i.e., it's equivalent to `((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.row)).removeAllViews()`. Basically, your `removeAllViews(R.id.row)` call was emptying the first row, but leaving the `LinearLayout` behind, which is why the other rows wouldn't shift upward. Just FYI.

Comment: Yes, I realized that afterwards. I changed my message because it is an error, but the problem was that it only deletes the first id it finds, and if I run it twice when the first one is deleted, the second line is not deleted either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding this answer because Mike M found the solution. [Mike. M Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145285/remove-programmatically-generated-layout-in-widget-usin-remoteview?noredirect=1#comment122210316_69145285)

Don't know if it's the better way of doing this but its works

I save RemoteViews of my rows in an Array.
Each time I update the widget I fill the view with the RemoteViews of my array. Recreating all the layout tree of my list.

Before each update, I can now remove or add row to my ArrayList which will display what I want.

```
ArrayList<RemoteViews> rows = new ArrayList();

// Adding rows : rows.size() = 3
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    RemoteViews rowView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
    rows.add(rowView);
}
// Removing a row : rows.size() = 2
rows.remove(2);

// Update the Layout
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.removeAllViews(R.id.list_container)
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    views.addView(R.id.list_container, rowView);
}
// Only 2 rows appear
```

Another problem was to acces specific Element in my row, but this can be done usin the same method. RemoteViews.settextviewtext(id) only search the id in their childen so I can acces to element in the rows because they have distinct id in it.